# Oracle: update table using dynamic column names

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, dynamic-columns, dynamicquery

I am using Oracle 11g. My tables include columns like name and l_name (lowercase of name column). I am trying to iterate through all the columns in my table space to set the l_ columns to lowercase of their respective uppercase columns. Here is what I tried:

```
for i in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
    SELECT SUBSTR(column_name,3) bulk collect into my_temp_storage FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = i.table_name and column_name like 'L\_%' escape '\';
    for j in (select column_name from user_tab_columns where table_name = i.table_name) loop
        for k in 1..my_temp_storage.count
        loop
            if(j.column_name like 'L\_%' escape '\' and SUBSTR(j.column_name,3) = my_temp_storage(k)) then
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'update ' || i.table_name || ' set ' || j.column_name || ' = LOWER(' ||my_temp_storage(k)|| ') where ' || j.column_name || ' is not null');
                execute immediate 'update ' || i.table_name || ' set ' || j.column_name || ' = LOWER(' ||my_temp_storage(k)|| ') where ' || j.column_name || ' is not null';
            end if;
        end loop;
    end loop;
end loop;
```

I am storing all the names of columns in uppercase in my_temp_storage and updating the table with the LOWER value of the columns in my_temp_storage. This gave me an error saying:

```
Error report -
ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
ORA-06512: at line 8
00900. 00000 -  "invalid SQL statement"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

But the DBMS output seemed to be fine:

```
`update EMPLOYEE set L_NAME = LOWER(NAME) where L_NAME is not null`
```

Could you help me with the way I did or any other way it can be done?

Comment: This is the only thing on my work sheet and line 8 contains the ' execute immediate' statement

Comment: You don't have `begin` and `end` around this? And a declaration for `my_temp_storage`?

Comment: Do you have any tables or columns named with reserved words or keywords, and/or quoted identifiers? What happens if you run this with the execute immediate commented out?

Comment: I am sorry. I did not properly understand your first comment. I thought you were speaking in context of above posted code. I do have all that stuff, but I just posted my logic part. Even then the error is being shown up at the line with the execute statement!

Comment: As I have posted, the dbms output is running fine. If I comment the execute line, all the queries are being printed in the output

Comment: Is the example you've shown, with `name`, the last output you get before the error? If not, what is? Trying your code, `name` doesn't generate that error.

Comment: That is the only line I see in the console. So, what I thought might be happening is, it is running the first dbms output line and throwing an error at the execute line

Comment: Wait, is the output *exactly* as you showed, with the single quotes around the whole update statement? That *would* get ORA-00900 - but the code you posted doesn't generate the output or the statement with the quotes.... Without the quotes it's fine, as you said in the question.

Comment: It's actually without the quotes. I think I selected the code twice while posting which opened those quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program could certainly be simplified:

```
begin
    for i in (select table_name, column_name from user_tab_columns 
              where column_name like 'L\_%' escape '\') 
    loop
        l_sql := 'update ' || i.table_name || ' set ' || i.column_name 
                  || ' = LOWER(' ||substr(i.columm_name,3)
                  || ') where ' || i.column_name || ' is not null';
        execute immediate l_sql;
    end loop;          
end;
```

It seems an odd database design though.  Have you considered virtual columns, and/or function-based indexes, instead of manually maintained columns?

Comment: I tried something similar at first. But, the LOWER('||substr(i.columm_name,3)) returns the sub string from the same column (that is L_ column).

Comment: It is substringing the **name** of the column not its value, so it doesn't matter?

Comment: This is working. Thank you so much. The way I tried before is : LOWER( substr(' ||i.columm_name|| ',3) which actually gave lowercase values of same column